# Import a external less file into an app.component.less file using Webpack

Tags: angular, import, webpack, less, angular2-components

Angular 2 application

I have a less file at `assets/less/color.less` which contains some variables.

```
@submenu :  #003C4F;
@sidebar :  #00495D;
@hover :    #006673;
```

I need to be able to access these variables in my component's less file located at `app/app.component.less`. I am using "webpack" to manage my files.

How do you import an external `.less` file into a component's `.less` file using "webpack"? Doing a simple import **doesn't** seem to work, as shown below.

```
//app.component.less

@import "assets/less/prm-color.less";

.grid-side {
  height: 100%;
  width: 45px;
  background-color: @sidebar;
}
```

Everything compiles fine, I just get an error for that variable in the inspector.

> Invalid Property Value

Here are my less-loaders:

```
module: {
 loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.less$/,
    loader: 'raw',
  },
 ]
},
```

Comment: Ignore the inspector, does it compile? Have you configured the less-loader etc.

Comment: @JohnMee: Thanks for the response. I made changes to the question above and added the less-loader info.

Comment: Post the error.

Comment: @JohnMee Re-added the error

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to do the same when I found your question. The issue for me was that I had to use a relative path instead of absolute.

So for me I had to import it the following:

```
@import "../assets/less/prm-color.less";
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the loader. It was set to `raw`, it should be changed to the following:

```
module: {
 loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.less$/,
    loader: ["css-loader", "less-loader"],
  },
 ]
},
```